# Paint the active category with a different color

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, categories

I have a `taxonomy-blogs_taxanomy.php` file. Inside the file, I display the category names and also go to them by reference. Now I need to make sure that the active category in which I am is closed with some color. Please help.

```
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms( 'blogs_taxanomy', array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_taxanomy',
        ) );  
    ?>


foreach ( $terms as $term ) {   
                  
    <div class="blog-container-control center" >
            <div class="col-12 pt-2 pb-2 blog-container-inner-control">
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><span class="link"><?php echo 
                    $term->name; ?></span><a>
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

I need the link of the category I am currently on the page to be filled in.

Comment: Add `active` class to this element, in CSS set required color for that class, we don't know how do you determine when category is active.

Comment: @biesior if I add the class "active ", then it will be added for everyone at once, so I need to somehow find out that exactly the category I am on is active and assign a class to it

Comment: Add it only to **this** active element, most probably using `if` statement. Once again, we're not able to guess how it is recognized as *active* as you don't show us that.

Comment: Well that you add this only dependent on a _condition_, was probably implied … So what is your actual problem now? Finding out what the current category is? Well then do a bit of _research_ to find out! “wordpress taxonomy template get category” typed int Google, led to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/280772 real quick.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I don't know how to determine whether this particular category is active in order to add an IF to it

Answer (score 0):

I use this and this work. Thank all for help

```
$categories = get_queried_object();
$category_name = $categories->name;
$cat_name =  $term->name;
 if( $category_id == $cat_name) { ?>
   <div class="col-lg-4 active">
   </div>
}
```